# When Azure cloud service provide Load balancing between multiple instance, Why traffic manager required?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-traffic-manager

I am a beginner at cloud service. I come to know that Azure Cloud service automatically do Load Balancing with multiple instances, Then Why we need Traffic Manager? Can you explain difference?

Comment: I already upvoted and marked it as a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Major difference is that Azure Traffic Manager can designed to distribute traffic globally (Multiregional environments) and you could implement failover/failback with traffic manager easily. It also comes with Layer7 network protocol

Azure Load Balancer can only route traffic inside an Azure region and it comes with Layer4 only